# How to prove this property of a projective transformation?

Tags: lie-groups, transformation, projective-geometry

The copy below is from this book:

- Sophus Lie, *Vorlesungen über Differentialgleichungen
  mit bekannten Infinitesimalen Transformationen*, bearbeitet und
  herausgegeben von Dr. Georg Wilhelm Scheffers,
  Leipzig (1891). Availability:
  [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009T8GNPA) ,
  [bol.com](http://www.studieboekencenter.nl/aanbod/isbn-9785879251753-vorlesungen-uber-differentialgleichungen-mit-bekannter-infinitesimalen-transformationen-bearb-und-hrsg-von-georg-scheffers-german-edition), [online at GDZ](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN578426625).

A *projective transformation* of the plane is represented by two equations of the form:
[image]

If you don't understand German, let the formulas speak and forget the rest.
The text says that the above transformation $\;(x,y) \to (x_1,y_1)\;$ is the most general that transforms a straight line into a straight line, both
in the Euclidian plane. Despite of trying to understand the content of this page
for about a week, I have not a clue what the purported
proof is all about.
Can somebody please clarify things a bit? My knowledge
about projective geometry is minimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the author is essentially saying is this: 
solve the $x_1=...$ and $y_1=...$ for $x$ to get
$$ \big((d+e\kappa)x_1-a-b\kappa\big) x + (em+g)x_1-bm-c = 0$$
and
$$ \big((d+e\kappa)y_1-h-k\kappa\big) x + (em+g)y_1-km-l = 0 $$
This can be written in matrix form 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} (d+e\kappa)x_1-a-b\kappa & (em+g)x_1-bm-c \\ 
(d+e\kappa)y_1-h-k\kappa & (em+g)y_1-km-l \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Since the vector $(x,1)$ is nonzero, regardless of $x$, that means the matrix must have zero determinant. That's what the last equation in the text says. The author argues that the $x_1y_1$ terms cancel and that only $...x_1+...y_1+...=0$ is left. That's the equation for a line.

Answer (score 1):

He starts with a generic projective transformation. Using homogeneous coordinates and matrix notation, I'd rewrite his equation (4) like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\1\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\h&k&l\\d&e&g\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

He then considers that line $y=\varkappa x+m$ and applies the projective transformation to ots result, obtaining the equation for $x_1$ and $y_1$. Then comes the removal of the variable $x$. For that, let's rewrite his equations by cross-multiplying the denominator:

\begin{align*}
\bigl((d+e\varkappa)x+em+g\bigr)x_1&=(a+b\varkappa)x+bm+c \\
\bigl((d+e\varkappa)x+em+g\bigr)y_1&=(h+k\varkappa)x+km+l
\end{align*}

Next, rearrenge to obtain equations in $x$:

\begin{align*}
\bigl((d+e\varkappa)x_1-(a+b\varkappa)\bigr)x&=(bm+c)-(em+g)x_1 \\
\bigl((d+e\varkappa)y_1-(h+k\varkappa)\bigr)x&=(km+l)-(em+g)y_1 \\
\end{align*}

Or written still differently, in vector notation:

$$
x\begin{pmatrix}
(d+e\varkappa)x_1-(a+b\varkappa) \\
(d+e\varkappa)y_1-(h+k\varkappa)
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
(bm+c)-(em+g)x_1 \\
(km+l)-(em+g)y_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So you are asking about when one vector will be a multiple of another. You may remember that a solution can only exist if the vectors are linearily dependent, i.e. if their determinant is zero. So that's what we check.

$$
0 =
\begin{vmatrix}
(d+e\varkappa)x_1-(a+b\varkappa) & (bm+c)-(em+g)x_1 \\
(d+e\varkappa)y_1-(h+k\varkappa) & (km+l)-(em+g)y_1
\end{vmatrix} \\
= \bigl((d+e\varkappa)x_1-(a+b\varkappa)\bigr)\bigl((km+l)-(em+g)y_1\bigr) \\
- \bigl((d+e\varkappa)y_1-(h+k\varkappa)\bigr)\bigl((bm+c)-(em+g)x_1\bigr) \\=
\bigl((d+e\varkappa)(km+l)x_1-(a+b\varkappa)(km+l)+(a+b\varkappa)(em+g)y_1\bigr)
\\ -
\bigl((d+e\varkappa)(bm+c)y_1-(h+k\varkappa)(bm+c)+(h+k\varkappa)(em+g)x_1\bigr)
\\ =
\bigl((d+e\varkappa)(km+l)-(h+k\varkappa)(em+g)\bigr)x_1 \\
+ \bigl((a+b\varkappa)(em+g)-(d+e\varkappa)(bm+c)\bigr)y_1 \\
+ \bigl((h+k\varkappa)(bm+c)-(a+b\varkappa)(km+l)\bigr)
$$

So he obtains the equation of a line $y_1=\varkappa_1 x_1+m_1$ with

$$\varkappa_1=-\frac{(d+e\varkappa)(km+l)-(h+k\varkappa)(em+g)}
{(a+b\varkappa)(em+g)-(d+e\varkappa)(bm+c)} \\
m_1=-\frac{(h+k\varkappa)(bm+c)-(a+b\varkappa)(km+l)}
{(a+b\varkappa)(em+g)-(d+e\varkappa)(bm+c)}$$

which demonstrates that the transformation maps lines to lines.

Comment: Hence $1 = d x + e y + g$ ? How can that be - I understand equality ? If not, what does $\sim$ mean in this context ?

Comment: $\sim$ here is the equivalence of homogeneous coordinates. It means that the vecotr to the right is a multiple of the one to the left. That's one way to avoid the fractions used in Lie's lecture: instead of writing the same fraction for every coordinate, you have a separate coordinate to carry that denominator.